# Retina and Non Retina Graphics in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game in iphone already developed one year back in older version of cocos2d.

Now i want to upgrade the game with both retina and non-retina graphics for all iphone3G,3GS and 4+ devices.

I have used many buttons and CCMenus how can i handle them in code. Do i have to write conditions for every graphic?

Any help or tutorial?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, its cocos2d accepts only CC wrapper.

Comment: No, we have a class called CCFileUtils in cocos which supports retina but how to use it we don't any help on net..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement HD "Retina Display" graphics in Cocos2D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951046/how-to-implement-hd-retina-display-graphics-in-cocos2d)

Answer (score 3):

No, you dont need to do the conditional coding.... You can have the retina display support bye either un-commenting or adding the below code into your appDelegate.m/.mm file in the applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

Also you need to add "-hd" suffix image files for the retina display of the iPhone.

For cocos2d version 2 you need the "-ipad" & "-ipadhd" files to be present in your Resources folder.

To upgrade the cocos2d version you can follow the steps on this [Link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0).
But cocos2d version 2 supports 3GS and above iPhone.

Hope this information would help you.

Answer (score -2):

As I know, the iOS will do this for you if you name the image file in a correctly way.
ex: 
normal screen: banner.png
Retina screen: banner@2x.png

The only thing you need to do is name the higher resolution image by a same name with the lower one and add subfix "@2x"

Comment: Cocos2d doesn't use the @2x method